# Unconditional Variance of X

Tags: self-study, variance

The random variables X and Y are related as follows: 
$X$ conditional on $Y = y $ has a $N(2y, y^2)$ distribution.
$Y$ has a $N(200, 100)$ distribution.
Derive the unconditional variance of $X, V[X].$

My attempt,

$$V(X)=Var[E(X|Y)]+E[Var(X|Y)]$$
$$=Var(2y)+E(y^2)$$
$$=4Var(y)+E(y^2)$$
$$=4\cdot100+(200^2)$$
$$=40400$$

But the given answer is $40500$. Why?

Comment: your approach is correct.

Comment: $E(Y^2)=(E(Y))^2+\operatorname{Var}(Y)$.